# Pandas.concat on Sparse Dataframes... a mystery?

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

Why when concatenating 2 dataframes, the result is Sparse... but in a weird way ? How can I evaluate the memory occupated by the concatenated Dataframe ?

I wrote you guys a code sample to better understand the issue :

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              'B': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              'C': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              'D': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              'E': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]},
            index=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']).to_sparse(fill_value=0)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'F': [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              'G': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
              'H': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              'I': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              'J': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]},
            index=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']).to_sparse(fill_value=0)

print("df1 sparse size =", df1.memory_usage().sum(),"Bytes, density =", df1.density)
print(type(df1))
print('default_fill_value =', df1.default_fill_value)
print(df1.values)

print("df2 sparse size =", df2.memory_usage().sum(),"Bytes, density =", df2.density)
print(type(df2))
print('default_fill_value =', df2.default_fill_value)
print(df2.values)

result = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)

print(type(result)) # Seems alright
print('default_fill_value =', result.default_fill_value) # The default fill value is not 0 ???
print(result.values) # What's that "nan" blocks ?
# result.density # Throw an error
# result.memory_usage # Throw an error
```

And more generally : Is anyone know what's happening over here ?

Comment: What is your numpy and pandas version?

Comment: pd.__version__ => '0.17.0'
np.__version__ => '1.10.1'

Comment: I can't say whether this is a bug or not but the same thing happens on pandas `0.17.1` np `1.9.3` maybe worth posting this as an issue on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Comment: Thanks, I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12174)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem and there is an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12174) for it.

Comment: An issue that I just opened (please refer to my comment above)